# Using a Arduino Mega instead of a Uno for a capacitive sensor

Tags: arduino

I was trying to use a Arduino Mega to substitute a Arduino Uno. The folliwing code works fine in Uno but doesn't work on Mega (I already changed the ports to it). It is used for a Capacitive touchsensor:

```
#define resolution 8
#define mains 60 // 60: north america, japan; 50: most other places

#define refresh 2 * 1000000 / mains

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // unused pins are fairly insignificant,
  // but pulled low to reduce unknown variables
  for(int i = 2; i < 14; i++) {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
  }

  for(int i =22; i < 53; i++){
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
  }

   pinMode(8, INPUT);

  startTimer();
}

void loop() {  
  Serial.println(time(8, B00100000), DEC);

} 

long time(int pin, byte mask) {
  unsigned long count = 0, total = 0;
  while(checkTimer() < refresh) {
    // pinMode is about 6 times slower than assigning
    // DDRB directly, but that pause is important
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
    PORTH = 0;
    pinMode(pin, INPUT);
    while((PINH & mask) == 0)
      count++;
    total++;
  }
  startTimer();
  return (count << resolution) / total;
}

extern volatile unsigned long timer0_overflow_count;

void startTimer() {
  timer0_overflow_count = 0;
  TCNT0 = 0;
}

unsigned long checkTimer() {
  return ((timer0_overflow_count << 8) + TCNT0) << 2;
}
```

I would like to know what I need to change on the Timer interrupt stuff to make it work properly.

Comment: You haven't explained what specifically doesn't work properly. Please edit your question to provide a detailed description of the problem, so that we can help.

Comment: `while((PINH & mask) == 0)`?